# Using a variable in an upstream declaration?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to use a variable in an nginx upstream directive?

```
upstream appserver {
    server unix:/socks/$host.sock
}
```

I've search my little heart out and can't find the answer.

A) Is it possible?
B) Is this a terrible idea?

Comment: Did you try it?  The easiest way to determine if it's possible is to try it...

Comment: I did and it didn't work, but I was asking because I didn't know if the host variable had a different name in the upstream directive or if variables needed to be passed to the directive for them to be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to do that kind of a configuration.

You are better off doing the following:

**General config:**

```
http {
    ...
    include upstreams/*.conf;
    ...
    server {
        ...
```

**upstreams/*.conf:**

Use a script to generate these files with changing variables for you and then reload config with `nginx -s reload`

**Example python script:**

```
from os import system

upstream = "something"
with open('upstreams/bro.conf', 'w') as f:
    f.write('upstream {0} {{\n\tserver unix:/socks/{0}.sock\n}}'.format(upstream)
system('nginx -s reload')
```

Answer (score 4):

a) No.

b) Yes. Thought it could be useful for development config,

I see no problem with using this snippet in dev:

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/socks/$host.sock;
```

Comment: It works! I didn't know you could specify a proxy without defining an upstream. Nice. Can you elaborate on why it's a bad idea to use in production? Assuming host can only have one value... otherwise you have to create symlinks for each host and you are better off making static.

Comment: Because you would not be able to specify a pool of IPs for redundancy.